# New active record syntax for association conditions and with_options method

Tags: ruby, activerecord, ruby-on-rails-4

In new version of active record(4.x I guess) conditions syntax for associations like

```
has_many :items, conditions: { marker:true }
```

is deprecated. It should looks like

```
has_many :items, -> { where marked:true }
```

New syntax looks more sophisticated(in my opinion) but it becomes impossible to use it with `Object#with_options` method.

In older version my code was like

```
with_options conditions:{marker:true} do |assoc|
  assoc.has_many :items
end
```

But now it seems like I can't do it anymore.

Does anyone know any way to add condition to all my associations without copy/paste it again and again ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

After some digging, it seems like the block variable yielded from calling with_options responds differently when the last variable is a proc object. A workaround is to end the call with an empty hash.

```
with_options conditions:{marker:true} do |assoc|
  assoc.has_many :items, -> { where marked:true }, {}
end
```